# Node https forward proxy client-server

Tags: node.js, proxy, node-http-proxy

I'm trying to use Node's [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module to make a request to https url. Code snippet below.

```
var request = require('request')
,r = request.defaults(
      {'proxy':'https://localhost:8443',
        strictSSL: false, 
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
      });

function sendHttpsReq(){
r.get('https://my.https.url/api/model', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          console.log(body);
       }
    });
}
```

Using the above code, If i use a http proxy and make a http request, the proxy server gets the request. But for a https url through a https proxy, the proxy server never gets the request. I'm using a simple node-http-proxy based proxy server running on my local server.

Comment: Could it be that the https proxy presents a non-trusted certificate?

Comment: @NitzanShaked These options are supposed to by pass the certificate trust.`strictSSL: false,rejectUnauthorized: false`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like multiple people had issue with node-http-proxy when using it as https forward proxy.

The following issues are logged on their github repository.

https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/453

https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/454

I had to deviate from using node-http-proxy for https forward proxy instead used the code from following blog.

http://newspaint.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/node-js-http-and-https-proxy/

Comment: Could you share your version of the https forward proxy for comparison?

Comment: @jodytate I used a forked copy of this.
https://github.com/joeferner/node-http-mitm-proxy